# How to get a return value of a C exe file in TCL (Windows)

Tags: tcl, exec

I've been trying to use to use a catch and exec to run a compiled C program that returns an int at the end, but so far I can only get the return values of 0 and 1, 0 returning when the c program returns 0 and 1 for anything else.
Is there a way to get any return value (eg. 5) from the C program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Use the third argument to the `catch` command to retrieve the return options:

```
 set returnvalue 0
 if { [catch { exec ./myprogram } result retopts] } {
   lassign [dict get $retopts -errorcode] class pid retcode
   set returnvalue 1
   if { $class eq "CHILDSTATUS" } {
     set returnvalue $retcode
   }
 }
```

A `try / on error` block can also be used:

```
try {
  exec ./myprogram
  set returnvalue 0
} on error {result retopts} {
  lassign [dict get $retopts -errorcode] class pid retcode
  set returnvalue 1
  if { $class eq "CHILDSTATUS" } {
    set returnvalue $retcode
  }
}
```

**Edit:** `try / trap` example:

```
set returnvalue 1
try {
  exec ./myprogram
  set returnvalue 0
} trap {CHILDSTATUS} {result retopts} {
  lassign [dict get $retopts -errorcode] class pid retcode
  set returnvalue $retcode
}
```

References: [catch](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm) [errorCode](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/tclvars.htm) [try](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm)

Comment: Use a `trap CHILDSTATUS` clause on that `try`; it simplifies the code.